# PhotosDuplicateTagInBatch error when uploading / tagging photos in Facebook!

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, tagging

I am writing an application that allows users to upload multiple photos at once to facebook and it will automatically tag themselves (no one else) in the photo when this happens.

If I run the script once, it works fine, if I try to upload and tag multiple photos then it complains with a `PhotosDuplicateTagInBatch` error and I can't find ANY information as to why this is happening!

Here is my code:

```
  for ($i = 5; $i >= 1; $i--)
  {
        $img = GetImage($i);
        $tag = array(
            'tag_uid' => $facebook->getUser(),
            'x' => rand (0,100),
            'y' => rand (0,100)
        );
        $tags[] = json_encode($tag);
        $args = array(
          'message' => $i,
          'image' => '@'.realpath($img),
          'tags' => $tags,
        );

        $data = $facebook->api('/me/photos', 'post', $args);
    }

}
```

If I output my arguments they come out as:
Code:

```
Array
(
    [message] =>  4
    [image] => @imagepathhere
    [tags] => Array
        (
            [0] => {"tag_uid":"100002493436028","x":13,"y":68}
            [1] => {"tag_uid":"100002493436028","x":60,"y":57}
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So essentially, from what I can tell, you cannot upload and tag multiple photos like this.  What I had to do was upload the photo, then tag it separately and rinse and repeat